# Use value of primary set in where of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario.  I have two tables that need to be joined.  The first table is a master record.  The second table is a multi-row child record that needs to be ordered by a descending data and then only the top child record joined to the master record.  The only thing I can come up with is this:

```
WITH SCD as (select top 100000 Part_Id as PartID, [Date_Created]
      ,[Production_Part_Status_Id]
      ,[Operations_Labor_Rollup]
      ,[Operations_Materials_Rollup]
      ,[Purchased_Subpart_Rollup]
      ,[Production_Subpart_Rollup] from 
   Production_Part_Supplier_Cost_Detail order by Date_Created desc)
SELECT 
     pp.Part_Number 
    ,pp.Part_Name
    ,pp.Revision
    ,pp.EAU_Quantity
    ,pp.Drawing_Number
    ,pp.Net_Weight
    ,pp.Current_Price_Each
    ,pp.Buyer_Stock_Id
    ,pp.Current_Price_Each - 
        (COALESCE(Operations_Labor_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Operations_Materials_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Purchased_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Production_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0)) as [variance]
    ,case when pp.Current_Price_Each = 0 or pp.Current_Price_Each IS null then 0 else 
        (COALESCE(Operations_Labor_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Operations_Materials_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Purchased_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Production_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0)) / pp.Current_Price_Each end as [Variance Percent]
    ,pp.Variance * pp.EAU_Quantity as [Annualized Variance]
FROM 
    Production_Part AS pp 
left join (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SCD where Part_Id = PartID) ppscd on ppscd.PartID = pp.Part_Id
WHERE 
    pp.Buyer_Id = @buyer_id;
```

The problem I'm running into is that the WHERE in the subquery cannot reference a value of the master table.  How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your limiting `TOP` and `ORDER BY` appearing in different places, this might have *appeared* to work but then actually fail. I suspect you added the `TOP 100000` to the CTE to "shut the query optimizer up" but what you actually did was hide a bug.

Rather than using `TOP` and `ORDER BY`, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead:

```
;WITH SCD as (select Part_Id as PartID, [Date_Created]
      ,[Production_Part_Status_Id]
      ,[Operations_Labor_Rollup]
      ,[Operations_Materials_Rollup]
      ,[Purchased_Subpart_Rollup]
      ,[Production_Subpart_Rollup]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Part_ID
                          ORDER BY Date_Created desc) as rn
   from 
   Production_Part_Supplier_Cost_Detail)
SELECT 
     pp.Part_Number 
    ,pp.Part_Name
    ,pp.Revision
    ,pp.EAU_Quantity
    ,pp.Drawing_Number
    ,pp.Net_Weight
    ,pp.Current_Price_Each
    ,pp.Buyer_Stock_Id
    ,pp.Current_Price_Each - 
        (COALESCE(Operations_Labor_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Operations_Materials_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Purchased_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Production_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0)) as [variance]
    ,case when pp.Current_Price_Each = 0 or pp.Current_Price_Each IS null then 0 else 
        (COALESCE(Operations_Labor_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Operations_Materials_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Purchased_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0) + 
        COALESCE(Production_Subpart_Rollup, 0.0)) / pp.Current_Price_Each end as [Variance Percent]
    ,pp.Variance * pp.EAU_Quantity as [Annualized Variance]
FROM 
    Production_Part AS pp 
left join SCD ppscd on ppscd.PartID = pp.Part_Id and
                       ppscd.rn = 1
WHERE 
    pp.Buyer_Id = @buyer_id;
```